# App Pool taking much memory in ASP.NET in IIS (20 GB)

Tags: asp.net, iis, memory, application-pool

I deployed my application in IIS server. It is using by all users where from all regions. it is running by `24X7`.The memory of app pool accumulated. It is taking 20gb of the memory. Can anyone please suggest me why It is happening? and how it can be solved?

[Memory Consumption Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3lt9D.png)

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you might have a bug in your application. Anyway you can configure the app pool to recycle after reaching a defined limit [here.](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725749(v=ws.10).aspx)

Comment: Hi Nick, many thanks for your response, application should run always , if i ll configure the same what you have suggested in the above, end user may interrupted (Logout happened). it is not good to implement here.

Comment: Hi Nick already i implemented your suggestion in PROD environment. it is recycled once per day. i can not go more than one per day, it will impact to end user.

Comment: Could you please tell me what are all things i need to check if is there any bug in my application?

Comment: Hi Vetri, There are a large amount of troubleshooting you need to do, There are some paid tools that will auto-asses your app and help. Try this guide and see if it gets you anywhere. http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/performance-issues/troubleshooting-native-memory-leak-in-an-iis-7x-application-pool

Comment: Thanks Nick, let me to go through and tell you. but already i analysed by debug diag tool for dump which is taken from PROD app pool.